# Unable to use hook in HOC for functional component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, higher-order-components

Using HOC to render functional component ie. SampleComponent here does work for me.

```
const SampleComponent: FC = () => {
  return (<div>Hello World</div>);
};

export default HOC({ component: SampleComponent });
```

And HOC is->

```
const HOC = ({ component: Component }) => {
  return (() => <Component/>);
}
```

However I want to render this component conditionally , something like this-

```
<div> 
{!id ? ( <SomeOtherComponent prop1={'hello'} prop2={'world'} /> ) : ( <Component /> )}
</div>
```

Here id is coming as a response from graphql query hook, which again i am unable to use in HOC function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, hooks are meant to be a replacement for HOC.

However, you can definitely use hooks in a HOC which is a function component. Only thing, you need to ensure is that you are using hook in a component that is rendered and not a function.

For instance use a hook like below is incorrect since you do not render HOC component but use it like `const X = HOC(Component);`

```
const HOC = ({ component: Component }) => { 
  const id = useQuery(query);
  return (() => <Component/>);
}
```

The correct way to do it would be

```
const HOC = ({ component: Component }) => {
  return () => {
     const id = useQuery(query);
     return (<div> 
         {!id ? ( <SomeOtherComponent prop1={'hello'} prop2={'world'} /> ) : ( <Component /> )}
     </div>)
  }
}
```

[**Working sample demo**](https://codesandbox.io/s/bitter-dream-ly4t5?file=/src/App.js)

However when you implement it like above, you are likely to receive a ESLINT warning because ESLINT is not intelligent enough yet to detect how the component is used. 
You can disable the warning for such scenarios

Comment: This didnt work,

Gettinng error->

React hook useQuery() cannot be called inside a callback. React hooks must be called inside react functional component or react custom hook function

Comment: @Prernashah You are likely to get a warning because of the fact that ESLINT is not intelligent enough to detect what you are trying to do. I added a working sample demo to prove that it does work. You can disable the warning for such scenarios

Comment: @Prernashah You are likely to get a warning because of the fact that ESLINT is not intelligent enough to detect what you are trying to do. I added a working sample demo to prove that it does work. You can disable the warning for such scenarios

Comment: Also while testing the HOC vi React testing library , getting the same issue React hooks must be called inside react functional component or react custom hook function. Do you know how this can be fixed?